# Using Razor templating engine on mac

Tags: .net, razor

I've been asked to redo the HTML and CSS for a website built on .net and which uses the Razor templating engine. It would be easy enough to simply go through all the Views and cshtml files and swap out the old markup with my own and to also include my own CSS. But how would I be able to do this on a mac? Is there any way to preview my changes and do testing in my browser if I'm using a mac?

Your knowledge is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If those views are just simple .cshtml files without things like `@Html.RenderPartial` you should be able to treat them just like simple, static HTML files and do the development the way you always do. Maybe you would have to replace `@Script` and `@Styles` Razor tags with pure HTML equivalent, but it should work.

If those views are heavly using a lot of Razor features, then I think you would have to run whole solution inside Visual Studio for you to be able to change things. Right now there is this cool new tool called Visal Studio Code, which runs on Windows, Linux and Mac, but

> Note: VS Code does not support debugging applications running on the Desktop .NET Framework.

What you could use is Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free, but runs only on Windows, so I think you would need to set up some virtual machine with Windows and do your work there.